# Does Android supports .wav audio?

Tags: root-access, audio, stock-android

In many internet blogs I read that wav audio files are not supported by Android OS. I have also tried to play .wav audio files with the default music player software in Android, but it couldn't be played.

But, recently when I peeped into the media folder in Android's system partition, (/system/media/alarms), I found many .wav files there.

Now I am confused. Does Android supports wav files ?

Comment: What's the Android version and the phone model?

Comment: Micromax Bharat 3 Q437

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Android supports .wav audio files.

The [Supported media formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats) lists the audio & video formats supported by Android, and .wav audio is among the many listed.

**Supported file type(s) / Container format** (only audio file types are listed below)

```
 • 3GPP (.3gp)
 • MPEG-4 (.mp4, .m4a)
 • ADTS raw AAC (.aac, decode in Android 3.1+, encode in Android 4.0+, ADIF not supported)
 • MPEG-TS (.ts, not seekable, Android 3.0+)
 • FLAC (.flac) only
 • GSM(.gsm)
 • Type 0 and 1 (.mid, .xmf, .mxmf)
 • RTTTL/RTX (.rtttl, .rtx)
 • OTA (.ota)
 • iMelody (.imy)
 • MP3 (.mp3)
 • Matroska (.mkv)
 • WAVE (.wav)
 • Ogg (.ogg)
 • Matroska (.mkv, Android 4.0+)
```

Comment: But as I had mentioned, that I was unable to play .wav files using the default music player. Are there different types of wav codecs ? OR is the default music player app doesn't support wav files ?

Comment: Try another music player (VLX, MX player, etc), and test if it can play or not.

Comment: Yes, those can play wav audios.

Comment: Then the problem is with the native music app on your phone. Because as the link provided in the answer, encoding wav is supported since Android 4.1 and decoding has always been present.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your response. Have a nice day :)

Comment: The [specifications](https://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/15e945b5) of your phone show that it is able to handle wav audio (on the page go to "Audio file formats/codecs"

Comment: If my answer is satisfactory, you can mark it as an answer